Google Ads Target Location ID / Description in readable form
I've got client targeting many locations such as "Dallas Texas + 25 miles surrounding".
The API (using Supermetrics) returns the field target_location as "Unknown location: 1603441562541"
Is there a way inside of the Google Ads User Interface to see a list of location ID's along with the written description of the ID? (the goal is to map these ID's number with a readable description inside a data studio report)
